# Python Error Handler

Tags: python, add-on

Is it possible to write a full-proof error handler that will always show information to the user when executed? I'm looking to make something for development only, where I can test conditions in a specific function (any function) and throw the error when the conditions are not met. These extensive condition tests are for programming only, testing for programmer mistakes rather than user or machine problems. So they will all be turned off after development is finished (not even checked).

I've been raising exceptions thus far, but my exceptions don't always generate pop-ups, and they become easy to miss, only printing to the console. It seems like this happens inside of certain functions, outside of Blender classes. Is it possible to force exceptions to halt execution and/or always generate user messages? Or perhaps there is another reliable method?

Comment: Yes, by using an IDE which halts either when exceptions occur or on your manually set breakpoints. For instance with VSCode: https://github.com/JacquesLucke/blender_vscode

Comment: I've also successfully used PyCharm Professional with the Dr. Sybren's remote debugger script: https://github.com/sybrenstuvel/random-blender-addons/blob/master/remote_debugger.py

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about these. I'm using Visual Studio 2017, which doesn't seem well suited to working with Python/Blender. But I'm so close to finishing this add-on project, I would prefer to avoid adding the extra time I would need to switch and learn a new environment. I will definitely keep them in mind if I decide to create any projects in the future.

Comment: Visual Studio is very capable of debugging both Blender's C or C++ code as well as add-ons. There's even a tutorial in Blender's wiki: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Tools/Debugging/Python_Visual_Studio

Comment: I've tried that before, but I don't think I was following that guide. I will check that out. Thanks!